# How to set a parameter for JPQL like query?

Tags: java, jpql

I'm going to get data from database using LIKE expression. My purpose is getting limited data according to my prefix('Sam%'). I tried to execute a query like below. But I got an Exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of def that does not exist in the query string select o from Item o WHERE o.itemName like ':def%'.
```

My method is,

```
public List<Item> getSuggestedData(String def) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select o from Item o WHERE o.itemName like ':def%'");
        q.setParameter("def", def);
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

How can fix this error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you want to use `Like` operation in jpql than better use criteria api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select o from Item o WHERE o.itemName like ':def%'");
```

to

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select o from Item o WHERE o.itemName like :def");
```

Answer (score 1):

use `%` in setParameter like following

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select o from Item o WHERE o.itemName like ':def'");
q.setParameter("def", "" + def + "%");
```

where `:def` is behaving like variable. so you need to set `%` in value string